# PHPUnit: How to get Value of a CONST to a Mock?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, unit-of-work

I want to test this part:

```
if ($unitOfWork->getEntityState($entity) === $unitOfWork::STATE_NEW) { ....
```

I already have a MOCK of $unitOfWork. But UnitofWork hast a CONST "STATE_NEW" and I don't know how I can mock this? Because when I say, that method "`getEntityState`" retuns the value "`STATE_NEW`", I want to say, that `$unitOfWork::STATE_NEW` is equal to the return Value and so it is going the if-condition! 
Has anyone an idea?
I already tried:

```
$unitOfWorkMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('STATE_NEW')
            ->will($this->returnValue('STATE_NEW'));
```

...but doesn't work!
ALso this ist not possible:

```
$unitOfWorkMock::STATE_NEW = 2;
```

To get my Mock of the unitOfWork i Call:

```
private function getUnitOfWorkMock()
    {
        return $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
    }
```

Comment: Can you not just compare to the const from a normal class?  Simply compare that the value back is correct using $class::STATE_NEW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mock constants, as basically mock objects extends the real objects and they have all of their constants.

```
$unitOfWorkMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getEntityState')
        ->will($this->returnValue($unitOfWorkMock::STATE_NEW));
```

Comment: THANKS! I figured it out also! Thats the solution!